# Dark Aqua appearance/custom appearance for XCode 8.2

Tags: cocoa, themes, xcode8

I'm developing an app in objective-c using Xcode 8. (because old computer)

Currently, my only options for the NSView's appearance are (Default) Aqua, and Aqua.

[image: really now?]

However, in SDKs starting in 10.14, they've included Mojave's Dark Aqua.

[image: here's what I want.]

I've added the 10.15 SDK (https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases) and added it to XCode (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/) and set the project SDK to it. However, I still don't get the choice to use Dark Aqua.

What should I do? (Alternatively, I could use https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer, but when I build it [as it does not include a build with it], I get errors when using the .car it generates.)

[image: whyyyyyy]

With hope,

Conrad

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do?

Get yourself a VM app (e.g. VMWare Fusion, Virtual Box, Parallels) and build yourself a Mojave VM then develop & test your app within that.

You will pay a small performance penalty, that's an objective observation of course and YMMV – especially if you're doing heavy graphics – but developing in a VM is quite doable. Indeed when Apple release 10.16 betas, you want to get your software ready, and you don't have a spare machine, then installing it on a VM is far safer than risking it on your primary machine.

HTH